# How to detect list changes without comparing the complete list

Tags: list, erlang

I have a function which will fail if there has being any change on the term/list it is using since the generation of this term/list. I would like to avoid to check that each parameter still the same. So I had thought about each time I generate the term/list to perform a CRC or something similar. Before making use of it I would generate again the CRC so I can be 99,9999% sure the term/list still the same.

Going to a specfic answer, I am programming in Erlang, I am thinking on using a function of the following type:

```
-spec(list_crc32(List :: [term()]) -> CRC32 :: integer()).
```

I use term, because it is a list of terms, (erlang has already a default fast CRC libraries but for binary values). I have consider to use `"erlang:crc32(term_to_binary(Term))"`, but not sure if there could be a better approach.

What do you think?
Regards, Borja.

Comment: Look at `erlang:phash2`.

Comment: It is working really well. I suppose it is faster than (Term->Binary + CRC calculation), thanks for the idea!

Comment: The more important question is *Why would you not know if the list has changed?* This sounds like an X-Y problem, at a minimum. The way the question is asked doesn't make sense to begin with, as Erlang terms are immutable.

Comment: Going more specific, I have several "data colection" servers which each of them collecting the values of their input inside a list [{Input_ID, Value}] on their #State variable. When they have collect enough data they send a calculation request to a JavaNode which performs a long time mathematic. If an user has deleted or added new "Inputs" to the list, the result of the last operation request will have to be discarded. I would like to avoid to maitain a Bool Flag indicating a change was performed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more context it is a little bit difficult to understand *why* you would have this problem, particularly since Erlang terms are immutable -- once assigned no other operation can change the value of a variable, not even in the same function.

So if your question is "How do I quickly assert that `true = A == A`?" then consider this code:

```
A = generate_list()
% other things in this function happen
A = A.
```

The above snippet will *always* assert that `A` is still `A`, because *it is not possible to change A* like you might do in, say, Python.

If your question is "How do I assert that the value of a *new* list generated *exactly* the same value as a different known list?" then using either matching or an actual assertion is the fastest way:

```
start() ->
    A = generate_list(),
    assert_loop(A).

assert_loop(A) ->
    ok = do_stuff(),
    A = generate_list(),
    assert_loop(A).
```

The `assert_loop/1` function above is forcing an *assertion* that the output of `generate_list/0` is still exactly A. There is no telling what other things in the system might be happening which may have affected the result of that function, but the line `A = generate_list()` *will crash* if the list returned is not *exactly* the same value as `A`.

In fact, there is *no way* to change the `A` in this example, no matter how many times we execute `assert_loop/1` above.

Now consider a different style:

```
compare_loop(A) ->
    ok = do_stuff(),
    case A =:= generate_list() of
        true  -> compare_loop(A);
        false -> terminate_gracefully()
    end.
```

Here we have given ourselves the option to do something other than crash, but the effect is ultimately the same, as the `=:=` is not merely a test of equality, it is a *match test* meaning that the two do not evaluate to the same *values*, but that they actually *match*.

Consider:

```
1> 1 == 1.0.
true
2> 1 =:= 1.0.
false
```

The *fastest* way to compare two terms will depend partly on the sizes of the lists involved but *especially* on whether or not you expect the assertion to pass or fail more often.

If the check is expected to fail more often then the fastest check is to use an assertion with `=`, an equivalence test with `==` or a match test with `=:=` instead of using `erlang:phash2/1`. Why? Because these tests can return *false* as soon as a non-matching element is encountered -- and if this non-match occurs near the beginning of the list then a full traverse of both lists is avoided entirely.

If the check is expected to pass more often then something like `erlang:phash2/1` will be faster, but only *if the lists are long*, because only one list will be fully traversed each iteration (the hash of the original list is already stored). It is possible, though, on a short list that a simple comparison will still be faster than computing a hash, storing it, computing another hash, and then comparing the hashes (obviously). So, as always, *benchmark*.

A phash2 version could look like:

```
start() ->
    A = generate_list(),
    Hash = erlang:phash2(A),
    assert_loop(Hash).

assert_loop(Hash) ->
    ok = do_stuff(),
    Hash = erlang:phash2(generate_list()),
    loop(Hash).
```

Again, this is an *assertive* loop that will crash instead of exit cleanly, so it would need to be adapted to your needs.

The basic mystery still remains, though: in a language with immutable variables why is it that you don't know whether something will have changed? This is *almost certainly* a symptom of an underlying architectural problem elsewhere in the program -- either that or simply a misunderstanding of immutability in Erlang.